# Socket.io and Vagrant can't establish websocket connection

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io, vagrant

I've got a Vagrant box set up to port-forwards a socket.io application from internal port 5000 to external port 8081; when I try to connect from the client it starts long-polling the connection but I don't see any kind of response from the server and the server app never registers a connection attempt. The connection doesn't fail or return any error response code though, it just returns a 200 code with a blank response.

```
// Import utilities
var http = require('http'),
    socketIO = require('socket.io'),
    querystring = require('querystring');

// Init servers/external connections
var server = http.createServer(function baseHandler(req, res) {
        // console.log(req.headers);
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(JSON.stringify({
            message: 'This server only supports WebSocket connections'
        }));
    }),
    io = socketIO(server);

server.listen(process.env.socket_port || 5000, function() {
    var sockets = [];
    console.log('App connected');

});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Socket connected');
    console.log('Socket in rooms '+ socket.rooms.join(', '));
});
```

The same app works just fine when I'm trying to connect from the app running directly on my PC, so my code doesn't seem to be the problem here, especially given how it's basically duplicating the basic example in the docs; not really sure how to solve this from here.

Comment: Did you open up a TCP port forwarding instead of http?  Web sockets uses TCP not HTTP.

Comment: @JeffSloyer Vagrant forwarded ports are TCP by default, the HTTP protocol doesn't even factor in to Vagrant's networking setup IIRC.

Comment: Can you try doing a local request on your vagrant vm to make sure things are working?

Comment: Vagrant's working just fine from what I can tell so far; I've done a telnet request to the port successfully to verify that it's open for TCP connection and all of the other ports are connecting and serving up HTTP requests as they should be.

Comment: Can you post some of your client code that you are connecting to socket.io with?

Comment: ...and now I just found the problem, see the answer I'm about to post below for an example of my genius coding skillz at work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those really stupid bugs which crop up when you're working on two different problems with the same codebase at the same time. Here's the client-side code line which was breaking:

```
var socket = io('127.0.0.1:8081/?access_token=1d845e53c4b4bd2e235a66fe9c042d75ae8e3c6ae', {path: '/auth/socket.io'});
```

Note the `path` key is set to point to a subdirectory, `/auth`, which is a leftover from my work to get an nginx folder proxying to an internal port which the server was working on.

Comment: Years later, I find myself in the same situation - a silly client-side error! In case anyone else comes across this in future, my particular error was having my socket connect to 'localhost' which, obviously, only works on my development machine. Had forgotten I was originally only experimenting with socket.io and just got it up and running as quickly as I could!